# Scroll event handling like Twitter and Facebook

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, jquery-events

I've been trying to bind **scroll** event to an element on the page, and on scroll load more content like Twitter or Facebook do.

#### HTML

```
<div id="main-content">
    <ul class="event-list big row" id="event-list">
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#main-content {
    width: 984px;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #101010;
    width: 974px;
    padding: 10px 0 7px 0;
}
#main-content .event-list.big {
   width: 1080px;
   padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

#### JS code

```
$('#event-list').scroll(function() {
    var curScroll = $(this)[0].scrollTop,
        maxScroll = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height();

    console.log(curScroll, ' :: ', maxScroll);

    if ((curScroll >= maxScroll - 200) && !loading) {
        loading = true;

        $(this)[0].scrollTop = curScroll;

        $('.loading').fadeIn('fast');

        if (page <= $('.page').length) {
            loadMore();
        }
    }
});
```

The `scroll` event is not triggered when I scroll its even doesn't print out **curScroll** and **maxScroll**.

What may cause the problem at all, maybe CSS styles are wrong or my **js** code wrong?

Comment: Did you put the JS-code in $(function() { /** here **/ });? If not the element is not yet loaded by the time the code gets executed and thus the event not bound.

Comment: I also just read, that scroll is triggerd on window, frame, iframe and elements that have overflow: scroll. So I guess you should add overflow: scroll to #event-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example of what I believe you want with the scrolling event triggering.  Use the div as a scrollable region by setting 'overflow: scroll'.  Note: you will only get the scroll event if the list is long enough on the initial load.  (See the height property on main-content.  I'll leave the ajax loading up to you.  :)

CSS

```
 #main-content {
    width: 984px;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #101010;
    width: 974px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0 7px 0;
}
#main-content .event-list.big {
   width: 1080px;
   padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#main-content').scroll(function() {
              var curScroll = $(this)[0].scrollTop,
                  maxScroll = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height();

              console.log(curScroll, ' :: ', maxScroll);

              if ((curScroll >= maxScroll - 200) && !loading) {
                  loading = true;

                  $(this)[0].scrollTop = curScroll;

                  $('.loading').fadeIn('fast');

                  if (page <= $('.page').length) {
                      loadMore();
                  }
              }
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
<div id="main-content">
    <ul class="eventlist big row" id="event-list">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>0</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's the working fiddle example if you want to look:  http://jsfiddle.net/daves2000/6A5Yn/

Answer (score 3):

See http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

The scroll event is only triggered on elements like window, frame, iframe and ones that have `overflow: (scroll|auto)` and their content must be greater then the available width/height. So I suggest you add

```
#event-list {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

If you want to listen for when the user scrolls to a specific element, you should listen on the scroll event of window and then check for the scroll coordinates.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { /** ... **/ });
```

Answer (score 3):

When you set css property of your body something like

```
body {height: 100%;overflow: auto;} // or visible
Now, $(window).scroll();  will not work.
```

It will cause jquery scroll event to not work because the dom is not scrollable. So you must either remove overflow property or set it to scroll.